# Rails Models for a Meal Planning Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations, rails-activerecord

I am trying to develop an application where a user can create a `MealPlan`. For each meal plan, the user can assign up to **3 meals** (breakfast, lunch, dinner) **per day** (using the `Meal` model).

However, I am not sure about how to at this design wise (Associations and tables). My initial thought was to create the `MealPlan` table with 3 different columns per day (resulting in 21 columns), each containing the ID of the `Meal`, but I feel this is not a very good and clean approach.

In this scenario, the dates are not important. But the **days** are. So with the approach I mentioned before, the table would look something like this:

```
create_table :meal_plans do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :monday_breakfast_meal
      t.integer :monday_lunch_meal
      t.integer :monday_dinner_meal
      t.integer :tuesday_breakfast_meal
      t.integer :tuesday_lunch_meal
      t.integer :tuesday_dinner_meal
      t.integer :wednesday_breakfast_meal
      t.integer :wednesday_lunch_meal
      t.integer :wednesday_dinner_meal
      t.integer :thursday_breakfast_meal
      t.integer :thursday_lunch_meal
      t.integer :thursday_dinner_meal
      t.integer :friday_breakfast_meal
      t.integer :friday_lunch_meal
      t.integer :friday_dinner_meal
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :state
```

Comment: You could do an association for `MealPlan` (`has_many :meals`) and then write a custom validation to ensure 3 meals and other criteria.  Honestly though, if your application isn't that complicated, 3 columns on `MealPlan` is a perfectly reasonable design.

Comment: @SeanHuber Thanks for your reply. What I mean though is that it's 3 columns **per day** in the meal plan, so that would make it 3 columns for Monday, 3 columns for Tuesday, etc. etc.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. My answer doesn't change much though, your ideal database design likely depends on more information beyond the fact that a `MealPlan` consists of 21 `Meal` choices per week.  What is it that you are storing in the `meals` table?  21 columns feels like a bit much, but it is finite and a case could be made that the design works for the problem.  A more likely alternative would be that you have a join table with these columns: `meal_id`, `meal_plan_id`, `day_of_week`, and `meal_type` (`meal_type` representing breakfast, lunch, or dinner).  Add validations as needed.

Comment: How far ahead do you want them planning their meals?

Comment: @SeanHuber: Each column would basically just be a `Meal` id. So basically 21 different `Meal` ids.

@TimmyVonHeiss: They basically just assign 3 meals per day, so basically the `MealPlan` is based on a single week. It does not depend on dates or months.

Comment: You can have a `Day` model, a Day can has many `Meal`. User can have many `MealPlan`. In `MealPlan` model, you can store user id, meal id, day id.